# pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow

I am new to docker and python. I am running a **docker** image for **tensorflow** for image classification. I like to save the output into **SQL Server**. I have modified the python code for the insert. pyodbc was not working initially. Bow I have run below commands and it is working.

RUN

```
apt-get update && apt-get install -y gcc unixodbc-dev
```

RUN

```
pip install pyodbc
```

But I am still getting the below error while try to run the insert python script. What should I do next?

```
pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

Comment: cnxn = pyodbc.connect('Trusted_Connection=yes', driver = '{SQL Server}',server = '127.0.0.1', port='1433', user='sa', password='*****', database='****')

Comment: Any update on this? I am having exactly the same issue...